# Gremlin query to traverse nodes and edges based on user permissions (stored as node/edge property)

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, graph-traversal

In Janus Graph we are trying to achieve a logical separation of nodes and edges driven by the user's permission, which I think is not a very un-common requirement and people out there might have addressed this case already.

Unfortunately, Could not find a best fit solution to address this.

Our Janus Graph environment:

- we instantiate using gremlin server and enabled HttpChanelizer to be accessible only via HTTP request.

Approach:
if we store the permission as property of SET cardinality along with other properties in nodes and edges, options available is to post gremlin queries to a a new service (spring boot) and block gremlin ports (to stop allowing the generic gremlin query directly getting submitted to gremlin server).

on the new service (spring boot) side, planning to parse the query submitted and suffix with has("entitlement", textContains("team1")) for all the steps (out *, in *, both *, outE *, inE *, bothE *, outV, inV -- https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#walk) used in the query to walk or traverse the graph.

like a very simple travarsal query:
// Flights from London Heathrow (LHR) to airports in the USA

```
g.V().has('code','LHR').out('route').has('country','US').values('code')
```

to be parsed and added the entitlement check on each step of type walk, only if the user trying to run the query, is entitled with team1.

```
g.V().has('entitlement', 'team1').has('code','LHR').out('route').has('entitlement', 'team1').has('country','US').values('code')
```

not an expert in Graph/Gremlin though, any guidance to achieve this type of permission bassed gremlin query would be helpful.

Comment: it seems like https://stackoverflow.com/q/63684159/1831717 is a more refined version of this question? or are you asking something different here?

Comment: yeah.. this the intention of the other post. going through the proposed options.