# How to apply a static has step on all the visited nodes/edges for a given traversal gremlin query

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

We are stamping user permission as a property (of SET cardinality) on each nodes and edges. Wondering what is best way to apply the has step on all the visited nodes/edges for a given traversal gremlin query.

like a very simple travarsal query:
// Flights from London Heathrow (LHR) to airports in the USA

```
g.V().has('code','LHR').out('route').has('country','US').values('code')
```

add `has('permission', 'team1')` to all the visited vertices and edges while traversal using the above query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you may consider.

1. Write a [custom `TraversalStrategy`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#traversalstrategy)
2. Develop a [Gremlin DSL](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#dsl)

For a `TraversalStrategy` you would develop one similar to `SubgraphStrategy` or `PartitionStrategy` which would take your user permissions on construction and then automatically inject the necessary `has()` steps after `out()` / `in()` sorts of steps. The drawback here is that your `TraversalStrategy` must be written in a JVM language and if using Gremlin Server must be installed on the server. If you intend to configure this `TraversalStrategy` from the client-side in any way you would need to build custom serializers to make that possible.

For a DSL you would create new navigational steps for `out()` / `in()` sorts of steps and they would insert the appropriate combination of navigation step and `has()` step. The DSL approach is nice because you could write it in any programming language and it would work, but it doesn't allow server-side configuration and you must always ensure clients use the DSL when querying the graph.

> We are stamping user permission as a property (of SET cardinality) on each nodes and edges.

As a final note, by "SET cardinality" I assume that you mean [multi-properties](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-properties). Edges don't allow for those so you would only be able to stamp such a property on vertices.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, i.e. planning to use CustomUserPermissionStrategy. Note: we provide user to run gremlin queries via HttpChannelizer at the moment so we should use the new CustomUserPermissionStrategy in empty-sample.groovy like global <<[g: graph.buildTransaction().readOnly().start().traversal().withTravarsal(CustomUserPermissionStrategy.build())] 
Qns 1: where should we extract the user principle from the HttpRequest and invoke our entitlement engine rest API to get the user permissions? Is it doable within the CustomUserPermissionStrategy class or somewhere else?

Comment: you are going to have to write some custom code to make this happen. you will want to look at https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/2661f8207aee4095151191e542f99a5d5fbee722/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/handler/HttpGremlinEndpointHandler.java and modify that to your needs i think.

Comment: you would then take your custom handler and build your own `Channelizer` to construct your own pipeline and plug that into Gremlin Server: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/2661f8207aee4095151191e542f99a5d5fbee722/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server.yaml#L21

Comment: alright. thanks again. it seems I need to go deeper to know the complete workflow. any doc ref I can refer also how these custom classes needs to be plugged-in together. Note: we use janusgraph. btw.. do you mind talking on an instant messenger?

Comment: i'm afraid there usn't much documentation in this regard as it's a fairly advanced usage of the APIs (and netty's). if you have further questions, the gremlin-users mailing list might be a better way to chat...a bit better than IM as our discussions might help other users. in fact, if you search around in there a bit you might find past discussion that offer some guidance.  https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users

Comment: This is really helpful: https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/Ff0sHJk7JiE